# Comparing multiple polyline shapefiles to single key file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, comparison

I am working on a project where we are comparing participants' spatial memories. We take them through a circuit, then later in the lab they draw the route they traveled. I want to be able to compare this drawing against the actual route of travel. There are 40 in total, and I have them digitized and georeferenced, along with the "key" polyline file. there are 3 segments in each polyline layer. I am hoping to arrive at some sort of score - perhaps a "degree of difference". I had hoped to find a Levenstein dissimilarity tool or the like, but haven't found anything. Feature Compare seems to not be able to do this.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the key route + one of the drawn route? Buffering the key route and checking how much of the drawn route falls within the buffer might be an option.

Comment: Just an idea, but you could do something similar to what is suggested [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/43500), but just script it to run through all 40. You'd then have distance statistics for each you could compare. Perhaps using the mean or range as your degree of difference.

Comment: Hi Folks- I've been away from this site for awhile. I ended up just comparing the distances from actual waypoint to "memory" waypoint. This resulted in a Euclidean distance, but not really a score. I was hoping for a normalized scale of sorts that could do this. I'll post a few screencaps if people are interested.